# Customising UItababbar swift

Tags: swift, tabbar, iso

Can anyone point me how could I achieve such design in the UITabbar. I have tried adding the back-ground Image, but that does not look like the design. Here the curve is extended beyond the frame of UITabbar, not sure how to add this views on top of active tabbar.

[image: Tab bar with a curved top]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a custom TabBar from `UITabBarController` can be solved the problem. Instead of adding a direct image to the Tabbar, use an on the fly image using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` for `selectedTabBackgroundImage`.

1. Create the image.
2. Clip the top part round in the image

Here is the example of the code.

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
    
    var topClipSize: CGFloat = 24.5 //Adjust based on the number of tabbar
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let singleTabWidth: CGFloat = self.tabBar.frame.size.width / CGFloat((self.tabBar.items?.count)!)
        let singleTabSize = CGSize(width:singleTabWidth , height: self.tabBar.frame.size.height)
        // Create the backgound image
        let selectedTabBackgroundImage: UIImage = self.imageWithColor(color: .blue, size: singleTabSize)
        // Clip the top
        self.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = selectedTabBackgroundImage.roundTopImage(topClipSize: topClipSize)
    }
    
    func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        if size.height > 55 {
            topClipSize = 30.0  // iPhone 8 tabbar height is 53 and iPnone X is 83 - We need more space on top.
        }
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height + topClipSize)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context!.fill(rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return image!
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func roundTopImage(topClipSize: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(origin:CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: self.size)
    let rectBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x, y: rect.origin.y + (topClipSize * 2), width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height - (topClipSize * 2))
    let ovalBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x - topClipSize, y: rect.origin.y, width: rect.size.width + (topClipSize * 2), height: rect.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, 1)
    let rectPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rectBounds)
    let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: ovalBounds)
    rectPath.append(ovalPath)
    rectPath.addClip()
    self.draw(in: rect)
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
}
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to elegantly change the native UITabBar's appearance to that extent. Your options are to create a custom container view controller that acts like a UITabBarController, or just hide the default tab bar and implement your own view in that space.

Even though it's less elegant because you'd be just throwing a view on top of the default tab bar, I actually like that method because you retain the benefits of the native UITabBarController (calling self.tabBarController? from its view controllers, it already adjusts layout margins, etc).

To do this, in your subclass of UITabBarController hide the tabBar:

```
self.tabBar.isHidden = true
self.tabBar.alpha = 0
```

Then after implementing your custom view however you want, just set the frame of your custom view to self.tabBar.frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

For changing viewControllers, call this when the user taps one of your custom tabs:

```
self.selectedIndex = newIndex
```